# Cannot install any language with Postgres 9.2

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I've been using Postgres 9.2 on several different servers for some time, but on one specific database on one specific instance of Postgres I can't install any languages.

```
$ sudo su - postgres
$ psql
postgres=# select * from pg_language;
```

This shows `internal`, `sql`, `c`, and `plpgsql`.

If I connect to `myDb` and try again:

```
postgres=# \connect myDb
You are now connected to database "myDb" as user "postgres".
postgres=# select * from pg_language;
```

I only see `internal`, `sql`, and `c`. I have tried installing the language using `createlang` as shown in their docs and receive an error:

```
$ createlang plpgsql myDb
createlang: language installation failed: ERROR:  language validation function 2247 called for language 13 instead of 1
```

I can see that `plpgsql.so` is in the proper place — and it has to be for the `postgres` database to have it.

This is also not `plpgsql` specific as I get the same error message with `plpythonu`. I can install in the `postgres` database but not the `myDb` database.

The documentation and forums do not address this issue.

Comment: What do you get for `SELECT * FROM pg_pltemplate WHERE tmplname = 'plpgsql';`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for the comment. I get:

`tmplname | tmpltrusted | tmpldbacreate |     tmplhandler      |       tmplinline       |   tmplvalidator   |   tmpllibrary   | tmplacl`
`plpgsql  | t           | t             | plpgsql_call_handler | plpgsql_inline_handler | plpgsql_validator | $libdir/plpgsql`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `pl_language` catalog is broken.

You should see the following:

```
SELECT oid, * FROM pg_language ;

  oid  | lanname  | lanowner | lanispl | lanpltrusted | lanplcallfoid | laninline | lanvalidator | lanacl 
-------+----------+----------+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+--------
    12 | internal |       10 | f       | f            |             0 |         0 |         2246 | 
    13 | c        |       10 | f       | f            |             0 |         0 |         2247 | 
    14 | sql      |       10 | f       | t            |             0 |         0 |         2248 | 
(3 rows)
```

Instead, your entry for the `c` language (OID 13) seems to have 1 instead of 2247 for `lanvalidator`. Any idea how that happened? Did you manipulate the catalogs?

See if there are any other differences to the above in your `pg_language`.

The safe way to proceed would be to `pg_dump` your database, drop and re-create it and load the dump. That should take care of all catalog manipulations.

If you prefer to live dangerous, you can try the following as superuser:

```
UPDATE pg_language SET lanvalidator = 2247 WHERE oid = 13;
```